# Registering an application to open specific web links

Tags: hyperlink, associations

My question is the following:

When using software such as Skype, TVU player or several other applications, it is possible to use weblinks specifically formatted for this application to launch it with certain parameters. For TVU for example a link on a web page could be:

tvu://some-channel-id

Clicking on this launches the application, so somehow the tvu:// part must be associated to this application.

I would like to do something similar for our application, but could not find the appropriate terms to search for any information. Could someone help me out?

Comment: OneNote also has the capability. I think the syntax is something like onenote://file://... You may have better luck searching in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is both browser- and OS-specific. Take a look at [this page](http://www.amule.org/wiki/index.php/Ed2k_links_handling) for some details, using eDonkey (ed2k://) as an example.